# Following all steps from Python Quickstart example for Google Sheet API but got 403 error: Google Sheets API has not been used in project

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I followed all the steps here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

It is supposed to get the data from the example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0

I already enabled google sheet API (from the button in the Quickstart page) for a Desktop app, downloaded the `credentials.json` file, copy the code, run the example and got this error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting
> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/values/Class%20Data%21A2%3AE?alt=json
> returned "Google Sheets API has not been used in project 541475924224
> before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
> https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=541475924224
> then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
> the action to propagate to our systems and retry.". Details:
> "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links':
> [{'description': 'Google developers console API activation', 'url':
> 'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=541475924224'}]}]">

What is wrong here?

Comment: From the error message, when you access to the URL of `https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=541475924224`, can you confirm that Sheets API has already been enabled?

Comment: When I access, I got the error message ` You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page `.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason of your issue might be due to it. Here, I have 2 questions in order to correctly understand about your situation. 1. In your situation, is the project number of project, which retrieved `credentials.json` file, the same with `541475924224`? 2. About `credentials.json`, is that for OAuth2? I thought that the direct reason of your issue might be able to be understood from these answer.

Comment: The project id is not the same as project number above, but an auto-enerated name, .e.g when clicking `Enable the Google Sheets API` button, it prompts me a project name, I enter `Gsheet` and now the `project_id` key is something like `gsheet-1602659897333`. The file seems like `OAuth2` with the following keys: `"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"`.

Comment: Thank you for replying.When the flow of the quickstart is run, no error occurs. I could confirm that the flow worked again. And from your replying, I think that your `credentials.json` seems correct. So in the current stage, I cannot replicate your situation of `You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page`. I apologize for this. For example, when you create the file, what value did you select at "Configure your OAuth client"?

Comment: @Tanaike OP said "Desktop App" in his question.

Comment: You probably need to contact your admin and ask them to enable the api for this project.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your support. I could understand about it. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate the OP's situation. I think that I have to study more and more.

Comment: Hi ! Could you ask your admin to check if the Sheets API for your project is enabled? And if that is the case try to run it again and let us know how it went